# Android fragment back press without any data loss

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an application with navigation drawer when I click each navigation list new fragments will load. One of the fragment have listView. When I click this list load another fragment. Now I move to different fragments using navigation drawer. When I press back button every time I want to move to previous fragment without any data change.How can I do it?

I am loading fragment using the following code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentHome, fr);
            fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

**In short::  Every back press I want to load previous fragment without recreating it**

Comment: Instead of replacing fragment you can use add fragment else you can use a data model for temporary storage.

Comment: If I use temporary storage I can avoid this. But it is not easy to save data in local too much data inside that.

Comment: Yes! Then you have to use Sqlite for storing those data.

Comment: Storing data is currently not possible. Any other options?

Comment: While working with fragment,we knew that we loss data on destroy of fragment so either you have to use temp storage to store data or Sqlite there is no other option or as I said instead of replacing fragment use add fragment.

Comment: How to add fragments?

Comment: fragment won't lose their data. for eg, when u load fragment A->fragment B now fragment A view will only destroyed not their data your if it is a global variable. when u come back to faragment A view will recreated and data restored.

Comment: i will send you the code wait..

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this?? Share with us.

Answer (score 5):

I think this may help

Just Do `PopBackStack` from `Fragmentmanager`

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
```

And In that Fragment

```
View mView ; //this will be global

@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            if (mView == null) {
                // view will be initialize for the first time .. you can out condition for that if data is not null then do not initialize view again. 
                mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml,container, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mView;
    }
```

Comment: here mView always null?? Also for PopBackStack  I am also doing the same right? What's wrong in my code?

Comment: No , it will initialize for the first time . then it has some value once it initialize.  
Like if you `Fragmnet A -> FragmentB` then you backstack `FragmentB` then in class `Fragment A` you should implement this `oncreateview ` here when  `Fragment A` created first time then `mView` will initialize. after you can push `FragmentB` on that.. once `FragmentB`will pop than in `FragmentA` , `mView`will has it value.. you can put check on that

Comment: Check my question fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentHome, fr); Is this right or wrong?

Comment: @Amsheer, `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentHome, fr);` will push fragment in `fragmentHome` framelayout. and if fragment is already in stack. then just we need to `popBackStack()` to go to that fragment as described above.

Comment: I hope I did the same. I made changes as per your answer in getView. What is wrong in my creating fragment code?

Comment: @Amsheer,  I think you should try with this https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav . this library maintain all the stack of the all fragment and its state with back stack. and then you can use above answer. And you should maintain `onBackPress()` of the activity for selecting tab programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
public  void addFragment( final Fragment newFragment, final Fragment hideFragment) {
    final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.hide(hideFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, newFragment, newFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(hideFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Use this instead of replacing fragment.will solve your problem.

Comment: this is not a good solution as memory getting increase on adding fragments and there is no use of fragments. OP already doing in right way.

Comment: I knew, but what if he does not want to use any temporary storage or any other storage do you have any solution for that?

Comment: check the answer by Mayur raval it is the right way to achieve the OP needs.

Comment: After replacing fragment one with other if you go for thepopBackStack() Stack what you get,can you please tell me?

Comment: it will initialize for the first time . then it has some value once it initialize. Like if you Fragmnet A -> FragmentB then you backstack FragmentB then in class Fragment A you should implement this oncreateview here when Fragment A created first time then mView will initialize. after you can push FragmentB on that.. once FragmentBwill pop than in FragmentA , mViewwill has it value.. you can put check on that. (copied from comment)

Comment: Can you please send me a demo of this!!