# Back button to a fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a main activity with 2 fragments. One of the fragments is a form. After submitting the form, a new results activity is a launched which has a back navigation button. When I press this back button, I am taken back to the form, but my form is cleared. I want to retain all the data which I entered initially before submitting. How can I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992216/android-fragment-handle-back-button-press , https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal

Comment: My fragments are in main activity and the problem happens when I navigate back to it from the search result activity. I am not switching from one fragment to another

Comment: Go for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605669/android-fragment-back-press-without-any-data-loss?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by setting the launchMode of the activity that held the fragments as singleTop in the manifest file.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember about active / fragment lifecycle.
When you back to your activity / fragment you have to refresh method @onResume.
So if you forgot about @onResume method you have to implement overridden and put there your missing methods.

Comment: It is retaining the values when I press the hardware back button, but not the soft button in the app